# Synchronizing UIScrollView scrolling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have three UIScrollViews, `scrollView1`, `scrollView2`, and `scrollView3`. When `scrollView1` is scrolled then `scrollView2` should scroll horizontally with it, and when `scrollView3` is scrolled then `scrollView2` should scroll vertically with it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 14):

The UIScrollViewDelegate protocol includes scrollViewDidScroll:.

You could set the contentOffset of your subserviant scrollviews using setContentOffset in scrollView2 and scrollView3 from scrollView1's delegate's scrollViewDidScroll:

Comment: THANKS man, THANKS!!!! TTTHHHAAAAANNNKKKKSSS!!!!!!! That's exactly what I was looking for 18 hours now!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Just an extra note, to those already wondering: does this method take into account scrolling beyond the edges of the content area?  it does!  Let me put it this way:  if you want two scroll views to **act as one**, this *IS* the technique you want to use.  It looks great.  Thanks Roger!