# multiple UIScrollView

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview

let me straight to the point,

there was 3 scrollview like the attachment, and i'm confused for the delegate.
see the link :
[image screenshoot](http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/2189/screenshot20130226at112.png)

here it is :

1. **scroll 1** - vertical scroll only
2. **scroll 2** - can scrolling free (horizontal / vertical)
3. **scroll 3** - horizontal scroll only

and i want to make if i was scrolling **"scroll 2"** *horizontally* then the **"scroll 1"** was scroll too.
and if i was scrolled **"scroll 2"** *vertically* then the **"scroll 3"** was scroll too.

it would nice if there's a sample code / example about this.

regards,

sky.

Answer (score 2):

I did something similar to two NSTableViews, scrolling of one would make second scroll.

Here is the code for that:

*MyScrollView.h*

```
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface MyScrollView : NSScrollView

@property (strong) AppDelegate *app;

@end
```

*MyScrollView.m*

```
#import "MyScrollView.h"
//#define LogRect(RECT) NSLog(@"%s: (%0.0f, %0.0f) %0.0f x %0.0f", #RECT, RECT.origin.x, RECT.origin.y, RECT.size.width, RECT.size.height)

@implementation MyScrollView
@synthesize app;

- (void)reflectScrolledClipView:(NSClipView *)aClipView{
     [super reflectScrolledClipView:(NSClipView *)aClipView];


    //post a notification
    app=[[AppDelegate alloc] init];

    if (app) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"scrolled" object:aClipView];
    }

}    
@end
```

*AppDelegate.h*

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@property (strong) IBOutlet NSTableView *aTableView;
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSTableView *bTableView;
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSTableView *cTableView;

@property (strong) IBOutlet NSView *aView;
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSView *bView;

@end
```

*AppDelegate.m*

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

/*
 Unwanted methods are not shown here, like delegates, datasource, init etc
*/

-(void)scrollTable:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
    NSPoint globalLocation = [NSEvent mouseLocation ];
    NSPoint windowLocationForA = [[aView window ] convertScreenToBase:globalLocation ];
    NSPoint viewLocationForA = [aView convertPoint: windowLocationForA fromView: nil ];
    NSPoint windowLocationForB = [[bView window ] convertScreenToBase:globalLocation ];
    NSPoint viewLocationForB = [bView convertPoint: windowLocationForB fromView: nil ];

    if (NSPointInRect(viewLocationForA, [aView bounds])) { // i scrolled on A
        NSLog(@"Scrolled A");
        if ([[[aTableView superview]superview] isEqualTo:[[aNotification object] superview]]) {
            [bTableView scrollRectToVisible:[[aNotification object] documentVisibleRect]];
            [cTableView scrollRectToVisible:[[aNotification object] documentVisibleRect]];
        }
    }
    else if (NSPointInRect(viewLocationForB, [bView bounds])) { // i scrolled on B
        NSLog(@"Scrolled B");
        if ([[[bTableView superview]superview] isEqualTo:[[aNotification object] superview]]){
            [aTableView scrollRectToVisible:[[aNotification object] documentVisibleRect]];
            [cTableView scrollRectToVisible:[[aNotification object] documentVisibleRect]];
        }
    }
    else{ // i scrolled on C
        NSLog(@"Scrolled C");
        if ([[[cTableView superview]superview] isEqualTo:[[aNotification object] superview]]){
            [aTableView scrollRectToVisible:[[aNotification object] documentVisibleRect]];
            [bTableView scrollRectToVisible:[[aNotification object] documentVisibleRect]];
        }
    }
}


-(void)awakeFromNib{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(scrollTable:)
                                                 name:@"scrolled"
                                               object:nil];

}

@end
```

Comment: Wow..so its not that simple for implemented the scroll delegate, can i just use something like scrollviewdidscroll or something?

Comment: I searched for the above for almost 15 days and ended with the above code.

Comment: well honestly this makes me thing that i could use the tableview, for replacing the scroll-1. and scroll-2 is another view with scroll. but i'm still confused for the scrollview was scrolling parallel for scroll-2 and scroll-3, even the scrolltableview and scroll-2 if i wanted scrolling vertically.

Comment: I have used tableviews as it contains scroll view.

Comment: actually i wanted to make some tv-guide like sky-tv apps, or tvguide.co.uk, and i think they did it just by scroll and appearing image / grid view on their content. do you have any idea?

Comment: well..i'm just predicted about it, if I'm using the tabelview, how does the content-table scroll horizontally and doing parallel scroll on scrollview-3?

Comment: In my code, i scrolled the scrollView, i guess similarly that can be achieved.

Comment: ok anoop, thanks for your help, i'll try your method first, really appreciated for your answer and this discussion too. where else i could contact you? if you mind.

Comment: actually i looking something like this link --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672338/synchronizing-uiscrollview-scrolling , can anyone show me some example code please?